# Difference between update query with select subquery and one with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can someone please tell me the difference between the execution of below two queries.

```
Update SomeTable 
Set Field1= 1234
Where Field2 in (Select Field_2 from SomeOthertable where x= 1)
```

Vs

```
Update Sometable as ST
Inner join SomeOthertable as SOT
On ST.Field2 = SOT.Field_2 and SOT.X = 1
Set ST.Field1 = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand the difference in the execution, you would need to look at the execution plans.

Here is some guidance though:

- In general, `JOIN` is going to be faster than `IN` because there are more opportunities for optimization *and* `IN` removes duplicates.
- In the case of an `UPDATE`, any duplicates could cause performance issues, because the same row can be updated multiple times.  This won't affect the results, because the field value does not change.

Often `exists` has good performance characteristics:

```
Update SomeTable st
    Set st.Field1 = 1234
    Where exists (Select 1
                  from SomeOthertable sot
                  where sot.Field_2 = st.Field2 and sot.x = 1
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `SomeOthertable(field2, x)`.  The `JOIN` can also use this index, but `EXISTS` guarantees that matching rows are updated only once.